# Is there a good book about interesting grammar in any language?

Tags: grammar

I love reading about interesting differences in grammar in different languages, e.g. Finnish cases. Is there a good book, site or something else that treats "interesting things in grammar" in any language?

Comment: Although the question is quite interesting to me, I'm afraid it's off topic here because: **1-** it's not specifically about english; **2-** it's subjective (good book _for me_ or _for you_?); **3-** It doesn't have a definite answer (again subjective, everyone can propose a different book)... Unless you can rephrase it, but I doubt it considering the question itself, it will be closed. Have you read the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq)? (I suppose so, but just in case

Comment: Furthermore, suppose that even a book like this exists, it would be _HUGE_... I mean, consider all of [these languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers), such a book would have millions of volumes...

Comment: I suppose Dickens would be a good choice, because he has very interesting use of grammar.

Comment: There is an interesting & short & well organized grammar book called `<Grammar for English Language Teachers>`, it's very good & easy to read.

Comment: @EricWang Thank you. Does it cover other languages than English, then?

Comment: @HenrikN It's just about English grammar, it's neat & clear, so there are only about 400 pages.